# Как сбросить значение PlayerPrefs?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

По задумке, игрок набирает очки ,но мне нужно чтобы их можно было сбрасывать,но когда функция Restart вызывается ничего не происходит(вызываю с помощью Button)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ControllScores : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text Record;
public Text Score;
public Text PodcEtScore;

public int score;
public int record;
public float time;
private float timeStart;
void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("score"))
    {
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
    }
    timeStart = time;
}


void Update()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
    time -= Time.deltaTime;
    Record.text = "record: " + score;
    Score.text = "score: " + record;
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        record += 1;
        time = timeStart;
    }
    if (record > score)
    {
        Record.text = "record: " + record;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        Record.text = "record: " + score;
    }
    Invoke("PodcetScore", 0.2f);
    
}
void PodcetScore()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < record; i++)
    {
        PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record;
        if (i < 10)
        {
            PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record + " Bro, try again?...";
        }
        if (i >= 10)
        {
            PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record + " Not bad...";
        }
        if (i >= 50)
        {
            PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record + " Good";
        }
        if (i >= 100)
        {
            PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record + " Very good!!!";
        }
        if (i >= 200)
        {
            PodcEtScore.text = "Your score: " + record + " Boy Boy nixyu TI Machina";
        }
    }
    
}
public void Restart()
{
    PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("score");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя в `Update` переменная заново создаётся каждый кадр. То есть нет смысла её удалять, она тут же будет создана опять. Как вариант, попробуй в `Restart` не удалять `score`, а обнулять.